# How to pass parameters in view?

Tags: .net, maui

I have myViewModelIn which I have called folder picker

```
   public MyViewModel(IFolderPicker folderPicker)
    {
        _folderPicker = folderPicker;
    }
```

I want to bind it with child view. Which I am not able to do via view because of it's parameterized Constructor. So I have bind this context in xaml.cs of child view

```
public ChildView(MyViewModel vm )
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext= vm;
}
```

This is how I am adding child view in parent view

```
  <view:ChildView  Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="4"></view:ChildView>
```

Now I have one parent view In which I have to set this child view . While adding this child view in parent view it is giving me an error
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   XFC0004 Missing default constructor for "DemoApp.MVVM.View.ChildView".  DemoApp D:\Priti\Samples\DemoApp\DemoApp\MVVM\View\ParentView.xaml  45
How I can achieve this ?

Comment: Why do you need this child view? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: Do you want to trigger the event or command in the parent view's view model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you instantiate objects in xaml like this

```
<view:ChildView  Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="4"></view:ChildView>
```

then your class `ChildView` needs the default constructor (the one without any arguments)! Otherwise the .NET framework does not know how to instantiate your object.

A possible solution for your problem could be the approach to set your view model (which is hopefully set as `DataContext` of your parent control) also as `DataContext` of your child control. Nevertheless, you have to remove the ChildView constructor with the argument (and thus the default constructor will be used again)

```
<view:ChildView DataContext="{Binding DataContext}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="4"></view:ChildView>
```

Hope, my explanation was understandable and will work :)

Comment: Hello @Sandman I didn't get what actually I have to do in child and in parent view Can you please explain?

Comment: 1.) You cannot use a custom constructor in your class `ChildView`. So just remove it. 2.) You have to pass your view model to the child class too. The question is now "Where do you instantiate your view model?" and is it set as `DataContext` ...

Comment: Yes I did it I have set my parent data context to the child also but now it is showing unhandled exception.

Comment: Hi @PreetiJadhav, could you please post more code snippets or a basic demo so that we can help you better?